# Ember: Remove models in one request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I know how to delete multiple models with one line of code:

```
models.invoke('destroyRecord')
```

But this results in x calls voor x items. Is there a way to say in Ember `Remove all models with one call, where the ids are submitted as request data`?

Of course I can do it by writing my own ajax request

```
models.invoke('deleteRecord');
Ember.$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: JSON.stringify( models.map(function(model) { return parseInt(model.get('id')); }) ),
    contentType: 'application/json'
 }).then(function() {
     ...
 },function(reason) {
     ...
 });
```

but i wonder if something like this is already in the core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember-Data doesn't support deleting multiple records at once out of the box. (That is to say, the adapters and store don't really have built-in methods to do so.) To do it it one AJAX call, you'll have to make the call yourself (like you have).